# Broken Iterator code

Tags: ruby

Running `score([1,1,1,1])` should result in `1100`, but I'm getting `1000`, and am not sure why. I hope a rubyist can take a look at it and let me know what's going wrong. I have this code set up a particular way because it has to pass other tests besides this one. Here's the code:

```
def score(dice)
  score = 0
  done_nos = []
  dice.each do |die|
    unless done_nos.include?(die)
        if dice.to_s.scan(/#{die}/).length >= 3
          score += 
            if die == 1
              1000
            else
              (100 * die.to_i)
            end
          if die == (5 || 1)
            score += ((dice.to_s.scan(/#{die}/).length - 3) * 
                if die == 5
                  50
                else
                  100
                end
              )
          end
        elsif die == 1
          score += (dice.to_s.scan(/#{die}/).length * 100)
        elsif die == 5 
          score += (dice.to_s.scan(/#{die}/).length * 50)
        end
    done_nos << die
    end
  end
score
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's quite a lot of logic going on in one single method. It would be best to break that logic up into several smaller methods. This will make your code so much easier to test - using automated unit tests, or just in general while writing the code.

That said, here's the problem:

```
if die == (5 || 1)
```

...highly doubt that's doing what you think it is. Change it to:

```
if die == 5 || die == 1
# or
if [5, 1].include? die
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
  if die == (5 || 1)
```

to

```
  if die == 5 || die == 1
```

helps for me. `(5 || 1)` always returns `5`

Comment: In ruby `||` evaluates to the first truthy value or to `false`. `(5 || 1)` actually evaluates to `5`, not `true`.